# Passing a javascript array into <datalist> form tag

Tags: html

I'm reading a csv file with the javascript File API. I want to display those data in a datalist ( html5 tag). I'm using the same code as in http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. The array that is holding the csv data is named datacsv. I just don't know how to pass the array (datacsv[] at this case) into the datalist tag, in order to display the data. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using jQuery:

```
var datacsv = ['example', 'of', 'some', 'data'];

for(var i in datacsv){

    $('#my-datalist').append('<option value=' + datacsv[i] + '>');

}
```

In response to your comment, jQuery is a useful library for the *client-side* JavaScript language, so it will work off-line. If you're looking for a non-jQuery way of doing this, you can use this code:

```
var datacsv = ['example', 'of', 'some', 'data'];

for(var i in datacsv){

    var datalist = document.getElementById('my-datalist');

    datalist.innerHTML += '<option value=' + datacsv[i] + '>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My app has to work offline as well. Does jQuery permits that? (Sorry for the elementary level question. I'm just at the very beginning of web development)

Comment: jQuery (and Javascript, in general), is a client-side scripting language. It will work offline as long as your scripts don't require any server-side response (and the one suggested here doesn't).

Comment: @SteliosVoskos the best way to thank on SO is an accepted answer in my humble opinion...

Comment: Shennan, indeed! Thanks again :)